# How to force a reflow in javascript in webkit 1.2.5

Tags: javascript, dom, webkit, reflow

I've tried everything that is supposed to invoke a reflow but that isn't happening. I'm calling my test function 10 times to draw some element on my screen and I move that element through each iteration. That loop is executed immediately and in the end I get one picture instead of seeing the movement of the element on the screen.

It's as if when all work is done, reflow and drawing on the screen is invoked. But i want to see each drawing.

All the things I've tried didn't give any results. The only thing that works is alert(), but i don't need an interaction with user.

I'm using an webkit 1.2.5 if that helps.

If I'm not understandable enough I will try to explain better.

This the code I'm forcing to reflow

```
 var i = 0;
 for(;i<500;i+=50){
fTestInfo(i);
console.log("Test loop!!! "+i);
 }
```

The thing I nedd is to see a picture on my screen each time fTestInfo(i) is executed but instead, i only see the ending result.

fTestInfo depends on i it moves in left by the value of i.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just animating it all in the blink of an eye? Also, without some example code we are sort of in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using a for loop which typically means you misunderstand how timers work. The for loop is synchronously executed and you are probably setting all the timers at once.

Try this:

```
(function loop(i) {
    if (i >= 500) {
        return;
    }
    document.querySelector("div").style.left = i + "px";
    setTimeout(function() {
        loop(i + 1);
    }, 16);
})(0);
```

​
demo http://jsfiddle.net/UCfmF/

---

I suppose you mean getting a value like `.offsetWidth`? This is not guaranteed to make a visible reflow on the screen, browsers may wait for some time (read: until javascript execution stops) before actually attempting to paint anything on the screen even if you are doing actions that trigger reflows.

This means that if you append 1000 elements to the document, it will not trigger 1000 reflows. Even if you fetch `.offsetWidth` in between each iteration. It will just be calculated for you but not necessarily painted.

You need to move the elements with a timer as the end of javascript execution is when browsers flush out any queued reflows.

See http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=3#reflow

> As stated earlier, the browser may cache several changes for you, and
>   reflow only once when those changes have all been made. However, note
>   that taking measurements of the element will force it to reflow, so
>   that the measurements will be correct. The changes **may or may not not
>   be visibly repainted**, but the reflow itself still has to happen behind
>   the scenes.

Comment: I edited the original post. I know about that, how the reflows work, and I know that i may do 1000 of elements and it can perform only one reflow. I tried with the timer, i put it between that log and the function, but I only end up waiting longer and the result is the same. Is there some event that I can provoke, which is not visible, and it will force reflowing and painting?

Comment: @Shakal187 show your code, you are currently just looping, not using timeouts.

Comment: I'm having a problem in implementing this into my code. Do I need that bracket before function loop(i)? I'm real rookie in javascript

Comment: @Shakal187 yes you need everything I have except of course the condition for returning can be different, the timeout value and the manipulation of the div.

Comment: ok thanks it works now. i have one more question. Is this the most efficient way to do it? I mean, are there any faster solutions?

Comment: @Shakal187 not sure what you mean by that. Faster how?

Comment: without recursion for example, or without that time delay. I'm working on an embedded system, so the performance is the issue also :)

Comment: @Shakal187 there is no recursion, the call stack always ends at the setTimeout - the CPU actually rests in between timeouts. That said, using browser and javascript in an embedded system doesn't sound like a great idea...

Comment: Btw, you are welcome to use the [javascript chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) for discussion as comments are not really allowed to be used for it.  You can accept the answer by clicking the white checkmark on the left of the answer if your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the browser the opportunity to enter its event loop between each iteration.

Use `setTimeout` to schedule each iteration of the drawing:

```
function scheduledTestInfo(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        fTestInfo(i);
    }, i);  // calls each function 50ms apart
}

var i = 0;
for ( ; i < 500 ; i += 50) {
    scheduledTestInfo(i);
}
```

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work if the `i` value is incremented by less than 13 at a time. And it's still ugly to make multiple timeouts at the same time rather than chain them imo :P

Comment: yeah, I know.  Best not to try and code on 8 hours of jet lag :(